# The observation of changes barycenter of the solar system

Tags: solar-system

Is it possible to observation changes in the barycenter of the solar system?

There are graphics showing changes barycenter but they are made on the basis of computer simulation (E.g.: [here](http://img.bhs4.com/c1/c/c1ce801bf6423a3dbb86bf7289bc954d8c4be0b1_large.jpg) and [here](https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-118a1175c48f6ff2afd0183dd0040dd4?convert_to_webp=true)).

It is possible? If so, how?